# Does there exist a "wiki" for editing doxygen comments?

Tags: c++, git, documentation, wiki, doxygen

I'm working on a fairly big open source RTS game engine ([Spring](http://springrts.com/)). I recently added a bunch of new C++ functions callable by Lua, and am wondering how to best document them, and at the same time also stimulate people to write/update documentation for *a lot* of existing Lua call-outs.

So I figured it may be nice if I could write the documentation initially as doxygen comments near the C++ functions - this is easy because the function body obviously defines exactly what the function does. However, I would like the documentation to be improved by game developers using the engine, who generally have little understanding of git (the VCS we use) or C++.

Hence, it would be ideal if there was a way to automatically generate apidocs from the C++ file, but also to have a wiki-like web interface to allow a much wider audience to update the comments, add examples, etc.

So I'm wondering, does there exist a web tool which integrates doxygen style formatting, wiki-like editing for those comments (preferably without allowing editing any other parts of the source file) and git? (to commit the comments changed through the web interface to a special branch)

We developers could then merge this branch every now and then to add the improvements to the master branch, and at the same time any improvements by developers to the documentation would end up on this web tool with just a merge of the master branch into this special branch.

I haven't found anything yet, doubt something this specific exists yet, so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: +1, very cool indeed ... That could really be useful, probably also for "core developers" if it manages to make the editing experience of formatted docs better than that of editing (sometimes cryptic) markup.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't even thought of that :-)

Comment: given the overall positive feedback, I would consider starting a new question asking people if they'd like to use something like this (pro & cons) and possibly detail their requirements for such a "source code documentation wiki".

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try to find some time for it after my current exam period.

Comment: If you've any update on this post, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very cool idea indeed, and a couple of years ago I also had a very strong need for something like that. Unfortunately, at least back then, I wasn't able to find something like that. Doing a quick search on sourceforge and freshmeat also doesn't bring up anything related today.

But I agree that such a wiki frontend to user-contributed documentation would be very useful, I know for a fact that something like this was recently being discussed also within the Lua community (see [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaSource)).

So, maybe we can determine the requirements in order to come up with a basic working draft/prototype?

Hopefully, this would get us going to initiate such a project with a minimum set of features and then simply release it into the wild as an open source project (e.g. on sourceforge), so that other users can contribute to it.

Ideally, one could use unified patches to apply changes that were contributed in such a fashion. Also, it would probably make sense to restrict modifications only to adding/editing comments, instead of allowing arbitrary modifications of text, this could probably be implemented by using a simple regex.

Maybe, one could implement something like that by modifying an existing (established) wiki software such as mediawiki. Or preferably something that's already using git as a backend for storage purposes. Then, one would mainly need to cater for those Doxygen-style comments, and provide a simple interface on top of it.

Thinking about it some more, DoxyGen itself already provides support for generating HTML documentation, so from that perspective it might actually be interesting to see, how DoxyGen could possibly be extended, so that it is well integrated with such a scripted backend that allows for easy customization of embedded source code documentation.

This would probably mainly boil down to providing a standalone script with doxygen (e.g. in python, php or perl) and then optionally embed forms in the automatically created HTML documentation, so that documentation fixes/augmentations can be sent to the corresponding script via a browser, which in turn would write any modifications back to a corresponding branch.

In the long term, it would be cool if such a script would support different types of backends (CVS, SVN or git), or at least be implemented generically enough, so that it is easily extendible.

So, if we can come up with a good design, it might even be possible that such a modification would be generally accepted as a contribution to doxygen itself, which would also give the whole thing much more exposure and momentum.

Even if the idea doesn't directly materialize into a real project, it would be interesting to see how many other users actually like the idea, so that it could possibly be mentioned in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

EDIT: You may also want to check out [this](http://morch.com/content/documentation-git-and-mediawiki) article titled ["Documentation, Git and MediaWiki"](http://morch.com/content/documentation-git-and-mediawiki).

Comment: I just responded to another related SO question, about our current way of doing this without using such a wiki (obviously, we'd prefer having a wiki-solution instead that integrates well with SCM system used): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961601/how-to-get-the-structure-of-software-if-there-is-no-document/962169#962169